# UserManager: How to check if the code generated by GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync() was used

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I use UserManager's `GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync()` to generate and send the verification code to the new email. I'd like to check if the code has been used in an unauthenticated context and display a message to the user if the new email was verified already: "Your new email address has already been verified. Please log in".

Is there a method in UserManager to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no method in `userManager` can achieve your requirement, But  i think you can pass this success message by yourself. You can refer to this code:

```
            //I use this code to get the currently logged in user
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;

            var result = await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, newEmail, token);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Your new email address has already been verified. Please log in";
                return RedirectToAction("ChangeEmail", "Test");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Email change failed";
                return RedirectToAction("ChangeEmail", "Test");
            }
```

**Test/ChangeEmail**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ChangeEmail()
        {
          //use ViewBag to pass data from controller to view
            ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
            return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
//.....
<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
```

**If change email successfully, it will show message in the view**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Since I want to test in unauthenticated context, can I do this in a transaction and rollback? I want actual ChangeEmailAsync() to happen in authenticated context

Comment: HI@frosty,  This action Only use `_userManager.ChangeEmailAsync()`  to change the database once, So i think it's no need to use transaction. In my opinion, This action should be protected by `[Authrize]`, Bacause you don't want to let unauthenticated user to change your database, right? Actually, I test this demo in  authenticated context, So I use `var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;` to get the currently logged in user, Then Change this user's email. I have edited my answer.